# Flyway is unable to deremine default schema for schema history table

Tags: java, database-migration, flyway

I'm trying to integrate FlyWay to non-spring application
I have next class, which is executed on app start:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class Config {
    private static final String MIGRATIONS_PATH = "migration";
    private final static Dotenv ENV = Dotenv.configure().load();
    @Resource
    private static MariaDbDataSource dataSource;

    static {
        dataSource = new MariaDbDataSource();
        try {
            dataSource.setUrl(ENV.get(FlyWayParameters.URL.getParameter()));
            dataSource.setDatabaseName(ENV.get(FlyWayParameters.SCHEMA.getParameter()));
            dataSource.setUser(ENV.get(FlyWayParameters.USER.getParameter()));
            dataSource.setPassword(ENV.get(FlyWayParameters.PASSWORD.getParameter()));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("[ERROR] Database initialization failed. Possible problem with configuration");
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void onStartup() {
        Flyway flyway = configureFlyWay();
        flyway.migrate();
    }

    private Flyway configureFlyWay() {
        Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .locations(MIGRATIONS_PATH)
                .load();
        return flyway;
    }
}
```

I take db params from .env file(example):

```
FLYWAY_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost
FLYWAY_USER=test
FLYWAY_PASSWORD=test
FLYWAY_SCHEMA=testschema
```

SO dataSource is ok, flyaway is created, but when `migrate()` starts I'm getting exception:

```
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to determine schema for the schema history table. Set a default schema for the connection or specify one using the defaultSchema property!
```

I tried to add `.defaultSchema()` to flyway config object, but this didnt help. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Specify default schema for the connection in the FLYWAY_URL

In your case use
`FLYWAY_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test`